# VBA save file as after each iteration of for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that copies over all the missing tabs from one excel to another.

Up until this point, I managed for the macro to create two columns with tab names, which leads to column F populating with all the missing tabs that have to be copied. The last thing to do is to create a for loop that checks if in the column there is an empty cell, and if not copy the tab with the cell name from wb1 to wb2, and then save it. The problem is that the code below does not return anything.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

```
        'Copy the tabs over
        Dim myrange As range, cel As range
        Set myrange = wb_macro.Engine.range("F2:F100")
        
        For Each cel In myrange 'look at first 100 different tabs
            If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
                miss_tab = cel.Value
                wb_from.Sheets(miss_tab).Copy Before:=Workbooks(new_wb).Sheets(1)
            End If
        new_wb.SaveAs Filename:=sFolderPath_new & sFileName
        Next cel
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Can I debug a nested for loop? Sorry, I am quite new to VBA

Comment: Yes, press F9 on the line you want to have your breakpoint. Run your macro and you are good. F8 step into, shift+F8 step over..

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem (it was regarding type not being compatible in some lines)